# How do I quickly convert a bitmap from sRGB to linear RGB?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, renderscript

I am currently designing an application on Android Studio. I can quickly convert a bitmap from linear RGB to LMS or XYZ using Renderscript's color matrices. But it takes too much time to convert a bitmap from sRGB to linear RGB. Are there any resources that allow me to convert a bitmap's pixels all from sRGB to linear RGB quickly?

Comment: I found a solution: you can use renderscript's lookup table intrinsic. Basically just precalculate an array of bytes with size 256 for srgb to linear rgb and convert each value for r, g, and b channels using the array as a lookup table